# New values for categorical variable in Prediction dataset

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, random-forest, categorical-data

I am performing *regression* task using *random forest**.In my prediction set I am having *new levels for categorical variable** which are not present in training data .Currently I am performing one hot encoding to handle this.At present I am not getting considerable results. [This article is saying that it is not good to perform one hot encoding](https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/).How to handle this case?

Comment: Set aside an "other" column for new levels. You can't expect the model to perform well on variables it has not seen.

Comment: I am with Emre on this. Can I ask how you came up with those new levels?

Comment: If the categorical levels can be ordered, perhaps treat the problem as regression instead?